# Avoiding angular dependency injection with use of global object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, global-variables

I inherited some code that is using a global object to to store angular services. These services get attached to the global object in the run function of the angular module. My question is, can this lead to trouble down the road? What sort of trouble does this cause for testing? Passing around services like this seems a lot easier than injecting all of the services in each controller so I see why this is done. What are other arguments for not doing this? Here is some code to illustrate what I am talking about:

```
// vars
var globalObject =
{
    ng: {},
};

// Setup module
var myModule = angular.module("myModule", []);
myModule.config(doStuff);
myModule.run(setUpGlobals);

// Setup app globals
function setUpGlobals(ngRootScope, ngHttp, ngTimeout)
{
    globalObject.rootScope = ngRootScope;

    // angular services
    globalObject.ng.http = ngHttp;
    globalObject.ng.Timeout = ngTimeout;
}
setUpGlobals.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$http', '$timeout'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules and DI were introduced in Angular exactly to avoid relying on globals and improve modularity.

This is naive approach that only works if there is a single module and a single application instance. It will fail if there are several modules that can be used separately (including tests). It will produce awful bugs if there is more than one application instance on the page (for example, if Angular is used for non-SPA applications).

A monolith module hurts testability. Even if it is used like that, some options will be unavailable, e.g. injecting spied or stubbed services in `$controller(...)` - because a controller relies on globals.

`setUpGlobals` results in eager service instantiation. This may not be a problem for core services but will be a problem for services that don't need to be instantiated right now.

Less important concern is code size in minified application. `ng.$rootScope` can be minified to `a.$rootScope` but not any further. Annotated function should mention `'$rootScope'` string once, but `$rootScope` variable name can be minified to `a`. There will be improvements if a service is used more than once inside a function.

There's a lot of reasons [why global variables are bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad). Some of them won't be applicable in this case, other ones will.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that services get instantiated on demand. https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2715-services-and-factories-are-instantiated-on-demand-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: You're welcome. Most times this won't be a problem, but this can break functionality that relies on natural behaviour, e.g lazy loading.

Comment: one more question: do services act as singletons across different modules? They do for the same module but if module A and module B inject serivce 1, will service 1 be shared?

Comment: I think the answer to my question is that the service belongs to a module so service 1 will be shared.

Comment: Yes, they are shared. Services are singletons within same injector (i.e. application instance). That's the reason why code above will work in most cases but will introduce design issues in edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

This makes testing nightmaraish. Dependency Injection is great, because it means you can do some atomic tests, by mocking out the services you don't need. In a simple, non-convulted example, imagine a service that makes API calls via http, if you DI it in, your test can mock out the http and just fake a return, letting you test only the bits of code you want, and saving you from having a test that relies on the API, or worse a test suit that uses up your API calls. With the provider in the global scope, that's much more difficult to achieve.

Just one reason, i'm sure there are many others.

Comment: Actually, testing won't be that bad - as long as there's a single module, globals will be reassigned in each test. But the point this it doesn't have to be single. And there will be problems once it isn't.